# How does the compiler evaluates expression with multilple comparison operators inside of the if-statement?

Tags: c++, if-statement, comparison-operators

So I have this program that returns "result: true"

```
if (true == false != true) {
    cout << "result: true";
}
else {
    cout << "result: false";
}
```

even if we flip the comparison operators inside of the if-statement, the compiler still evaluates the expression to be true

```
if (true != false == true)
```

My question is:

1. How does the compiler actually evaluates the expression?
2. and to which comparison operator out of the two present inside of the if-statement, preference is given?

Comment: @alfC can you please kindly be more specific in your comments as to where my question lacks proper explanation.

Comment: I mean that it is useless to know because even if it compiles you don't want to have that code because it is impossible to understand. And more to the point, `(true != false == true)` is `true` (in C++) and if that is `true` then it doesn't mean what you really want it to mean in the real world. In other words, abusing the associativity of (in)equality is in general a bad idea in C++.

Comment: @alfC, thanks for the clarification. This was actually an assignment problem i had about evaluating expression with multiple operators and i know has no real world explanation. I just wanted to know how exactly the compiler evaluates this kind of expressions.

Comment: My question is how do **you** evaluate that expression? If the answer is "I don't know" (which would be my answer), then don't write it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to both of your questions is [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). The `==` and `!=` operators get the same precedence, meaning they will be evaluated in the order given.

So in `true == false != true`, is evaluated as `(true == false) != true` first statement `true==false` being false, the full statement now becomes `false!=true` which evaluates to `true`

Similarly, 2nd statement `true != false == true` becomes `(true != false) == true` which evaluates to `true` at the end

---

**EDIT**:

After reading @Pete's comment, I did some more reading. Apparently there is an associativity property related to these kinds of situations

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

> Operators that have the same precedence are bound to their arguments in the direction of their associativity. For example, the expression a = b = c is parsed as a = (b = c), and not as (a = b) = c because of right-to-left associativity of assignment, but a + b - c is parsed (a + b) - c and not a + (b - c) because of left-to-right associativity of addition and subtraction.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. I think my query is resolved.

Comment: No, this leaves out the actual answer, which is **grouping**. Some operators group left to right; some group right to left. For example, addition groups left to right, so `a + b + c` is equivalent to `(a + b) + c`. Assignment groups right to left, so `a = b = c` is equivalent to `a = (b = c)`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Interesting. Thanks, I did not know about that concept. Is there any source to read more about this?

Answer (score 0):

1. For this particular case, the compiler evaluates the expression from left to right, as "==" and "!=" are of equal precedence.
2. As mentioned above, these two operators have the same precedence.
   For more information check out [C++ Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: Since the two operators have the same precedence, the answer cannot be precedence. In fact, it's **grouping**, which that link refers to as "associativity".